# Showing php floating point values with fixed exponential value

Tags: php

I have the following two php operations:

```
echo 0.0069131851196289 / 294; // 2.3514235100779E-5s
echo 3.340357542038 / 361349; // 9.2441311364857E-6s
```

Is there any way to make php to show these numbers when they are outputed in a fixed, same exponential notation? The desired output I would like is this:

```
echo 0.0069131851196289 / 294; // 2.3514235100779E-5s
echo 3.340357542038 / 361349; // 0.92441311364857E-5s
```

Comment: I think you can not set this value. But you can compare and make them equal, and move the decimal point accordingly.

Comment: You could use `number_format` to get them a little more consistent.

Comment: I think expoential values are always shown with one non-zero digit before the decimal point, I don't think there's a way to change that.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Which parameter to `number_format` are you suggesting? I don't see anything related to the exponent.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [arbitrary precision math functions(bcmath)](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) or [gmp](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php). Either one could return the result with the precision you are looking for.

An example from the bcmath would

```
echo bcdiv('0.0069131851196289', '294', 128)
// outputs: 0.00002351423510077857142857142857142857142857142857142857142857142857142857142857142857142857142857142857142857142857142857142857
```

I would also recommend to read [PHP Float Data Type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) from the online manual. The warning part is quite enlightening.

Check also that bcmath is active in your `php.ini` file. If not set and restart the server. (or enable it via the `ini_set`)

```
bcmath.scale = 1
```

Additionally in case that the bcmath module/package is not installed you will need to download it.

Comment: This absolutely does not solve the issue, because instead of keeping the scientific notation, I will be getting standard notation with very long numbers. I am aiming to achieve a specific look, not a specific precision.

Comment: Apologies for that. Instead, it points to a direction that solves it. What I've suggested is a part of a viable alternative. But, you need to read, learn and think a bit how you can achieve your result with what you have and what PHP offers you.